# Making a new page template for a different product page

Tags: php, xml, magento, magento-1.7

I've been trying to figure this problem out for several hours now - I've made two page templates for the products one is named vxs-view.phtml and the other is view.phtml. There located in the same directory.

The solution I tried was to input

```
<reference name="product.info">
    <action method="setTemplate"> <template>catalog/product/view/vxs-view.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

However this only works if that product is in a certain category. Is there a way I can add the pay layout to the template files in the design tab?

I've been adding this code to the front end system/custom design/ custom layout update box

Sorry I'm need to magento and still learning.

Thanks for any help

Comment: can you please add more detail. in which file you are adding this code?

Answer (score 1):

you are placing wrong reference type. Please try below code.

```
<module_page_action> <!- Enter your modulename_pagename_action e.g. catalog_product_info-->
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"> <template>catalog/product/view/vxs-view.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
<module_page_action>
```

Hope this will work for you!

Cheers!

Comment: Telling me there is an xml error with the code you provided dharmesh. adding </module_page_action>

Comment: here , <module_page_action> module = your current magento module (e.g catalog) , page = your page name like prouduct and action = page action like view. so your code will be like <catalog_product_view></catalog_product_view> , I hope this is enough to explain.

Comment: I couldn't seem to get this to work - so i wrote a query on the page template which just runs a conditional and swaps up the div's.

Comment: on which template page you have added condition vxs-view.phtm or view.phtml??